# How to add custom style to Google map in MAUI app?

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, xamarin.forms, maui

Is it possible to use custom map styles in MAUI using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map? I have the style in .json created but I don't see a way how to add it to the control. It seems to be possible in Xamarin forms, but not in MAUI at least not as easily. I am unable to find any reasonable answer anywhere. The only thing I found is this https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10706, but I am not much wiser after reading that. Please help.

Comment: As far as the current situation is concerned, you can continue to pay attention to that issue to see if there is any update. For MAUI, it still has many functions to be implemented...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a custom handler to the platform-specific code and adding the json file when the map loads in.
Use the code from here (you don't need everything if you don't use custom pins): https://vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/Customize-map-pins-in-.NET-MAUI/

My solution is the same as in the link you provided, but it doesn't work for them for some reason, maybe something's been fixed since then. Also, I've only tried it on android.

### Android

The important part is the OnMapReady function in the MapCallbackHandler class, you should use the json file here like this (as an embedded resource):

```
public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Mobile.light_map_style.json");
    string json = string.Empty;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream!))
    {
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    googleMap.SetMapStyle(new Android.Gms.Maps.Model.MapStyleOptions(json));
}
```

I haven't tried setting this up on iOS yet, I'd assume MKMapView has similar styling options that you can use from the platform-specific code.